# How to disregard 8.3 names when doing a DIR or FOR batch command

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I'm having trouble with file selection while trying to copy all files with a certain mask to another directory.

The code I came up with is:

```
FOR %%g IN (mylocation\T113*) DO (
copy %%g otherlocation\T113Files\
)
```

Files are named like `T11300A1_xxxxx` without an extension. In the same directory there are other files as well:

> ```
> T11200A1_xxxxx
> T14000A1_xxxxx
> ```

When Windows generates short names I have found how it behaves:

Beginning with Windows 2000, if at least 4 files or folders already exist with the same initial 6 characters in their short names, the stripped LFN is instead truncated to the first 2 letters of the basename (or 1 if the basename has only 1 letter), followed by 4 hexadecimal digits derived from an undocumented hash of the filename, followed by a tilde, followed by a single digit, followed by a period `.`, followed by the first 3 characters of the extension.

What happens is that short names of all my files are thus `T1hash`, and sometimes a `T14000A1_xxxxx` file can have a short name `T113xx~1` because the hash part is i.e. `1357` and then it gets transferred when it shouldn't.

Is there a way to tell the `for` loop to disregard 8.3 names and only look at long names?

Comment: `copy` takes wildcards, why would you use a `for` loop to copy files?

Answer (score 1):

If you really insist on using the FOR command then lets change it to a FOR /F and pipe the resulsts to FINDSTR so that you can actually match the correct file name. The full file name should be passed across the pipe so it should only match in the full file names.

```
@echo off
pushd mylocation
for /f "eol=: delims=" %%F in ('dir /b /a-d T113* ^|findstr /I /B "T113"') do (
    copy %%F otherlocation\T113Files\
)
popd
```

Comment: I'd add the `/I` switch to `findstr` in order to treat the file names case-insensitively, as Windows also does on its own...